# How to manage state separately of 2 different inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to manage the state of 2 inputs separately. Those 2 inputs have a floating label animation. When you focus on the input, the placeholder goes to the top and onBlur it gets back to its original position.

Right now I have a function named `handleFocusAndBlur` which where I need to implement that logic. For now the behavior is a bit weird since even when there is text only in one input, if you go to an empty input the label of the filled out input gets back to its original position, which shouldn't be that way.

This is the component I am using for that:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { View, TextInput, Animated } from 'react-native';
import styles from '../../styles/SigningScreenStyles';

export default class SigningInputs extends Component {
  state = { isFocused: false };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.animatedIsFocused = new Animated.Value(0);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const { isFocused } = this.state;
    Animated.timing(this.animatedIsFocused, {
      toValue: isFocused ? 1 : 0,
      duration: 200,
    }).start();
  }
  // SEE THIS FUNCTION
  handleFocusAndBlur = () => {
    const { usernameLength, passwordLength } = this.props;
    if (usernameLength || passwordLength) {
      this.setState({ isFocused: false });
    } else {
      this.setState({ isFocused: true });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { secureTextEntry, onChangeText, labelText } = this.props;

    const labelStyle = {
      position: 'absolute',
      left: 0,
      top: this.animatedIsFocused.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [10, -10],
      }),
      fontSize: this.animatedIsFocused.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [25, 14],
      }),
      color: this.animatedIsFocused.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: ['black', 'gray'],
      }),
    };

    return (
      <>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <Animated.Text style={labelStyle}>{labelText}</Animated.Text>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputs}
            onChangeText={onChangeText}
            onFocus={this.handleFocusAndBlur}
            onBlur={this.handleFocusAndBlur}
            blurOnSubmit
            secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
            propsLength
          />
        </View>
      </>
    );
  }
}

SigningInputs.defaultProps = {
  secureTextEntry: false,
};

SigningInputs.propTypes = {
  secureTextEntry: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.bool]),
  onChangeText: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  labelText: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string]).isRequired,
  usernameLength: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number])
    .isRequired,
  passwordLength: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number])
    .isRequired,
};
```

And this is how I am calling that component:

```
        const { username, password } = this.state;
        <SigningInputs
          onChangeText={user => this.setState({ username: user })}
          labelText="User Name"
          usernameLength={username.length}
        />

        <SigningInputs
          onChangeText={pass => this.setState({ password: pass })}
          secureTextEntry
          labelText="Password"
          passwordLength={password.length}
        />
```

When I had only one input it was pretty easy but now with 2 inputs I see that I need to implement some more logic.

Any chances someone may take a look?

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: Your `handleFocusAndBlur` logic has some flaws, consider this case: You focus, `handleFocusAndBlur` sets `isFocused` to true, your label moves. Now you type, go out of focus, now `handleFocusAndBlur` sets `isFocused` to false. So label moves again. Which it should not because there is text.

This could be solved if you remove `isFocused` state altogether. Because you don't need to know whether it is focused or not, you have two separate callbacks.
Add separate handler for focus and blur (as Jonathan Irwin's answer suggests)

```
<TextInput
     style={styles.inputs}
     onChangeText={onChangeText}
     onFocus={this.handleFocus}
     onBlur={this.handleBlur}
     blurOnSubmit
     secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
     propsLength
/>

handleFocus = () => {
    const { inputLength } = this.props;
    if (!inputLength) {
      Animated.timing(this.animatedIsFocused, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 200
      }).start()
    }
}

handleBlur = () => {
    const { inputLength } = this.props;
    if (!inputLength) {
        Animated.timing(this.animatedIsFocused, {
          toValue: 0,
          duration: 200
       }).start()
    }
}
```

You could just send the length as a common prop `inputLength` :

```
    const { username, password } = this.state;
    <SigningInputs
      onChangeText={user => this.setState({ username: user })}
      labelText="User Name"
      inputLength={username.length}
    />

    <SigningInputs
      onChangeText={pass => this.setState({ password: pass })}
      secureTextEntry
      labelText="Password"
      inputLength={password.length}
    />
```

Comment: When I do onBlur, the label gets back to its original position

Comment: I have updated the code and explained the wrong behavior from our previous discussion.

Comment: And what should I put on `componentDidUpdate`?

Comment: Just remove that completely.

Answer (score 2):

Splitting your handleFoucus and Blur works:

```
  handleFocus = () => {
    const {length} = this.props
    if (!length) {
      Animated.timing(this.animatedIsFocused, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 200
      }).start()
    }
  }

  handleBlur = () => {
    const {length} = this.props
      if (!length) {
        Animated.timing(this.animatedIsFocused, {
          toValue: 0,
          duration: 200
        }).start()
      }
  }
```

also remove the componentDidUpdate function, update your input onFocus and onBlur and only pass the length prop once (as suggested in the other answer)

Comment: This will make the label small on enter and on leave if the input is empty and not on leave if the input has a value